# differences between adding ip route to system and adding additional ip address

Tags: networking, routing, ip

I found that I can add an additional ip address to a network adapter which appears to be solving my problem of having multiple devices I need to talk to which are on different subnets (but same physical network).

Now I am wondering how this would differ from just adding a route in the routing table? So other than having an additional ip address what are the differences, when would you do one or the other?

The main issue I am trying to solve is the ability to talk to replacement devices on the network without being able to manually configure them, no GUI and no user. So my primary ip address is 172.16.1.1 and a camera was replaced that has a default address of 192.168.1.1. I have no ability to pre-configure or run the GUI setup for the camera (and other device types as well) but I need to talk to it.

Thanks

Comment: you have ip 172.61.16.1.1 and you wanna reach 192.168.1.1
and they are connected to the same switch ?

Comment: Yes, they are both on the same switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of scenarios for each case, but I'm going to list just one for each:

You'd add a secondary ip address when you want to communicate with devices that are on the same Layer 2 network but on a different Layer 3 network (devices that are connected to the same physical network but are using a different ip address range/subnet).

You'd add a route to your local routing table when you want to reach a different Layer 3 network that exists on a different Layer 2 network and the remote Layer 3 network is accessible via a router other than your default gateway. Most often you don't add routes for remote networks to your local routing table because all traffic for remote networks goes to/through your default gateway. You would add a route to your routing table if you wanted to use a specific (local) router other than your default gateway and when your default gateway doesn't have a route to the remote network.

These are just two possible scenarios for both cases.

Comment: The first scenario is what I am facing, and what I started doing.